# How to determine file system of TrueCrypt volume?

Tags: linux, filesystems, truecrypt

If a volume file is created by TrueCrypt, how do we determine what is the file system that volume is formatted?
Because if the file created from Linux, it can be ext3, if Windows, NTFS, but also FAT32. How do I determine the file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows, mount the virtual container on a drive letter. Make sure you have decrypted it. Then, go to My Computer, right-click on this newly mounted volume & click properties. Here, you can see what type of File System is being used.

In Linux, mount the virtual container on a mount point. Make sure you have decrypted it. Then, use following command in terminal:
`df -T`
Next to your mount point, you can see what type of File System is being used.

Comment: Thanks, but the df -T shows only "fuseblk", not the NTFS or ext3.

Comment: Then, file system is NTFS. Linux labels it as fuseblk file system when any NTFS volume is mounted (with read-write access) for non-root users. fuseblk is short for "FUSE Block". FUSE stands for "Filesystem in USErspace" and Block is for block devices.